# Isotope Filtering Gallery from database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-isotope

Sorry, I'm not too experience when it comes to coding, but trying to learn.

I'm using the Isotope plugin for an image gallery and I want to connect it to a mysql database instead of hard coding each image, title, category and description. Can someone help me get started?

Here is an example of the gallery I'm trying to use. It is all hard coded and I want to convert it to be database driven.

http://www.wiseguys-themes.com/wiseguys/creative/portfolio-filter-4columns.html

Here is what it looks like hard coded... with only one item displaying.

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Isotope filters
    ================================================== -->

    <section class="isotopeFilters clearfix">

      <ul class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".outdoor">Outdoor Living</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".bathrooms">Bathrooms</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".master">Master Suites</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".kitchen">Kitchens</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".dining">Dining Rooms</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".office">Office</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".great">Great Rooms</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".bonus">Bonus Room/Man Cave</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Responsive Filters
      ================================================== -->
      <form action="#" method="post" class="hidden">
          <select>
              <option value="">Categories</option>
          </select>
      </form>
    </section>

<!-- Isotope container
    ================================================== -->

    <section class="isotopeContainer portfolio left-twenty">


                <div class="element onefourth kitchen">

                    <div class="portfolioImage">
                        <a class="jackbox" data-group="work1" data-thumbTooltip = "Image Title" data-title="Image Title with <a href='http://themeforest.net/user/wiseguys' target=_blank'>link</a>"  data-description="#description_1" href="images/portfolio/1.jpg">
                           <div class="jackbox-hover jackbox-hover-blur jackbox-hover-magnify"></div>
                           <img width="225" height="170" src="images/portfolio/thumbs4/1.png" alt="" />
                           <span class="portfolioImageOver transparent"></span>
                       </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="portfolioText" data-targetURL="portfolio-single.html">
                       <span class="portfolioTextOver transparent"></span>
                       <p>Single image example</p>
                       <span>- illustration -</span>
                    </div>

                    <span class="portfolioArrow"></span>


                    <!-- Sample div used as an item's description, will only appear inside JackBox -->
                    <div class="jackbox-description" id="description_1">
                        <h3>Description Title One</h3>
                        <a href="#">Link</a> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In est metus, tincidunt vitae eleifend sit amet, porta a sapien. Fusce in dolor nec purus facilisis dictum. tincidunt sed quam. 
                    </div>



                </div>


    </section><!-- end isotope container -->
```

Here is my PHP. Of course I have substituted db_username and db_password in my actual file.

**PHP**

```
  <?      
          $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username", "db_password");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("gallery", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM entry WHERE  status = 'registered'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //Category ids
    $cat =  $row['id']  ;

    print "<p >" . $row['cat'] . "</p>";
    print "<p >" . $row['image'] . "</p>";
    print "<p class='title'>" . $row['title'] . "</p>";
    print "<p class='description'> Description: " . $row['description'] . "</p>";

    print "</div>";

}


mysql_close($con);         


             ?>
```

I can connect to the database, but not sure what the code should be to fetch all the gallery images to be displayed in four columns and is still filterable.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the code that Carlos provide but not getting it to work as needed. I did a little editing to the code to match what I have. It connects to the database but I think there is an issue with the output HTML. Here is what I have...

```
 <section class="isotopeContainer portfolio left-twenty">

    <?PHP
    //connect in db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db user', 'my db password', 'db name');

//check for error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}


//mount query 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE type=\'image\'';


//declare var array
$array = array();

//use query and make associative array.
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
//fetch associative array
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $array[] = $row;
}
}

/*use associative array and make html*/

//count array
$count = count($array);

//declare container var for html code
$html = '';

//note: but I think it's impossible to put link on titles. I think, in this case you  need to use fancybox and put link in description
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
$html .= '<div class="element onefourth illustration">'.
         '<div class="portfolioImage">'.
         '<a class="jackbox" data-group="'.$array[i]["cat"].'" data-thumbTooltip = "'.$array[i]["title"].'" data-title="'.$array[i]["title"].'"   href="http://holmesbydesign.com/test/galleryimages/'.$array[i]["url"].'>'.
         '<div class="jackbox-hover jackbox-hover-blur jackbox-hover-magnify"></div>'.
         '<img width="225" height="170" src="http://holmesbydesign.com/test/galleryimages/'.$array[i]["image"].'" alt="" />'.
         '<span class="portfolioImageOver transparent"></span>'.
         '</a>'.
         '</div>'.
         '<div class="portfolioText" data-targetURL="portfolio-single.html">'.
                        '<span class="portfolioTextOver transparent"></span>'.
                       '<p>'.$array[i]["description"].'</p>'.
                       '<span>- '.$array[i]["title"].' -</span>'.
                     '</div>'.

                     '<span class="portfolioArrow"></span>'.

                '</div>' ;
}

//and finally display html code
echo $html;
?>
</section><!-- end isotope container -->
```

You can see the code live here: http://holmesbydesign.com/test/portfolio2.php

Here is what I want it to look like: http://holmesbydesign.com/test/portfolio.php

The output is not correctly putting the closing div tags correctly. I'm trying to research and see if I can find a solution.

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Also, here is the info on the database.

The table is: gallery

The columns in the table are:

**id** (numeric 1, 2, 3, etc)

**image** (name of image, not complete URL... example: gallery_0cda5_image4.jpg)

**video** (URL of video)

**title** (example: Kitchen)

**type** (numeric, this is a select field in the uploader and pulls the type from the "type" table where 1 = image, 2 = video)

**cat** (numeric, this is a select field in the uploader and pulls the cat from the "cat" table where 1 = Exterior, 2 = Outdoor Living, 3 = Kitchens, etc.)

**description** (description to be used in the jackbox)

I'm not sure since there are three different tables used here if this is setup correctly in the code above.

I don't think the query is setup correctly.

Comment: You should edit your original question to add further information rather than add an answer which doesn't actually answer the question.  I will copy this into your question and flag it for mod deletion as 'not an answer'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need separate in database images, text and other, and in php you call from database and mount in a variable with your html code with database data.

something like:

```
//connect in db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

//check for error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}


//mount query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE type=\'images\'';

//declare var array
$array = array();

//use query and make associative array.
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    //fetch associative array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $array[] = $row;
    }
}

/*use associative array and make html*/

//count array
$count = count($array);

//declare container var for html code
$html = '';

//note: but I think it's impossible to put link on titles. I think, in this case you need to use fancybox and put link in description
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $html .= '<div class="portfolioImage">'.
             '<a class="jackbox" data-group="work1" data-thumbTooltip = "'.$array[i]["title"].'" data-title="'.$array[i]["title"].'"  data-description="#description_1" href="'.$array[i]["url"].'>'.
             '<div class="jackbox-hover jackbox-hover-blur jackbox-hover-magnify"></div>'.
             '<img width="225" height="170" src="'.$array[i]["thumb_url"].'" alt="" />'.
             '<span class="portfolioImageOver transparent"></span>'.
             '</a>'.
             '</div>';
}

//and finally display html code
echo $html;
```

For many options as in your case, you can make function.

And in your isotope you can random items with "sortBy : 'random'".

In any case, wait for postings from more experienced users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great start. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. I so appreciate you helping me!

Comment: @MattDuncan - Your answers both had zero upvotes or downvotes so the system orders them in random order as they are essentially equal.

Comment: I figured it out on my own!